# How to reset password of openstack instance using KVM and libvirt?

Tags: passwords, reset, openstack, kvm, libvirt

I'm using Openstack with KVM and libvirt. when I try to reset instance password with nova api, I received error 501 not Implemented! 
How can I change instance password?

Answer (score 2):

With KVM hypervisor resetting the password of an instance is not supported using nova 'root-password' due to limitations of KVM. The 'nova root-password' is only supported in xenapi with a guest agent running.

However you may inject password in instances at launching time on Libvirt-based hypervisors (KVM, QEMU, LXC).

For hypervisors such as KVM that use the libvirt backend, admin/root password injection is disabled by default. To enable it, set the following option in /etc/nova/nova.conf:

[libvirt]

inject_password=true

When enabled, Compute will modify the password of the root account by editing the /etc/shadow file inside of the virtual machine instance.

Users can only ssh to the instance by using the admin password if:

```
The virtual machine image is a Linux distribution
The virtual machine has been configured to allow users to ssh as the root user. This is not the case for Ubuntu cloud images, which disallow ssh to the root account by default.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use guestfish as it is explained [here](https://davidamick.wordpress.com/2013/09/16/regaining-root-with-guestfish/). Basically you need to install the tool:

`apt-get update
 apt-get install libguestfs-tools or guestfish (depends on your distro)`

Then you can modify directly the VM image (remember to shut down the VM before doing any modification to avoid corruption issues):

```
cd /var/lib/nova/instances/<your instance GUID>/
guestfish --rw -a disk -i edit /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

So you can include

```
PasswordAuthentication no
```

Then you can ssh your VM using the key you generated during creation. Or you can modify the password.

```
guestfish --rw -a disk -i edit /etc/sudoers
```

Include at the end of the file for instance

```
[USERNAME] ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Finally to change the password:

```
guestfish --rw -a disk -i command "bash -c 'echo USERNAME:PASSWORD | chpasswd'"
```

Answer (score 0):

You are receiving 501 because your instance does not have the qemu-guest-agent installed.

Here is a tutorial how to set the password in OpenStack for qemu-guest-agent instances:
https://osie.io/blog/how-to-set-passwords-for-openstack-instances-with-qemu-guest-agent

Note: This won't work for an existing instance. The instance must be created from an image with hw_qemu_guest_agent=yes property set. Otherwise, for existing instances you could manually edit the image properties in the DB and try hard-rebooting the instance.